# Why can't I convert this PDFMaker from xib to storyboard?

Tags: ios, xcode, interface-builder, uistoryboard

I need this small PDFMaker code in my larger code project, which is almost done expect for the PDFMaker.  My larger project is all done in storyboard, and the PDFMaker in xib.  I didn't see how you could do them both in the same project.  I used the Apple **"Converting to Storyboards Release Notes"** to convert the PDFMaker from xib to storyboard.  Pretty easy and straightforward.  However, I can't get either the `didClickMakePDF` or `didClickOpenPDF` selectors to work.  I keep getting the message

> unrecognized selector sent to instance

and a thread pointer to the `Main.m` file

```
return UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, NSStringFromClass([MTAppDelegate class]));"
```

line.  I'm new to coding and have been working on this for over 20 hours with no success.  All the actions and outlets seem to be set up fine in both the .h, .m, and storyboard files.  Could somebody please help me to fix this, or suggestion a different approach to be able to use this PDFMaker code in a storyboard-based project?

Here is my .h file:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "ReaderViewController.h"

@interface MTViewController : UIViewController <ReaderViewControllerDelegate>

- (IBAction)didClickMakePDF:(id)sender;
- (IBAction)didClickOpenPDF:(id)sender;

@end
```

Here is the relevant part of the .m file for the didClickMakePDF:

```
- (IBAction)didClickMakePDF:(id)sender {

    [self setupPDFDocumentNamed:@"NewPDF" Width:850 Height:1100];

    [self beginPDFPage];

    CGRect textRect = [self addText:@"This is some nice text here, don't you agree?"
                          withFrame:CGRectMake(kPadding, kPadding, 400, 200) fontSize:48.0f];

    CGRect blueLineRect = [self addLineWithFrame:CGRectMake(kPadding, textRect.origin.y + textRect.size.height + kPadding, _pageSize.width - kPadding*2, 4)
                                       withColor:[UIColor blueColor]];

    UIImage *anImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"tree.jpg"];
    CGRect imageRect = [self addImage:anImage
                              atPoint:CGPointMake((_pageSize.width/2)-(anImage.size.width/2), blueLineRect.origin.y + blueLineRect.size.height + kPadding)];

    [self addLineWithFrame:CGRectMake(kPadding, imageRect.origin.y + imageRect.size.height + kPadding, _pageSize.width - kPadding*2, 4)
                 withColor:[UIColor redColor]];

    [self finishPDF];
}
```

Here is the Main.m file:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

#import "MTAppDelegate.h"

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    @autoreleasepool {
        return UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, NSStringFromClass([MTAppDelegate class]));
    }
}
```

Comment: Select all objects on the XIB file, copy and paste them over to your storyboard.  Then copy/paste the code here to your view controller and hook up the IBActions.  Make sure you set the class of the UIViewController storyboard to the name of the UIViewController that you created.

Comment: Thanks. I've done that now 6-7 times, and still get this error.  Here is the full error message: 2013-06-05 17:10:48.327 PDFMaker[2678:19d03] -[MTViewController didClickMakePDF]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x9571820
2013-06-05 17:10:48.329 PDFMaker[2678:19d03] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[MTViewController didClickMakePDF]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x9571820'

Comment: I couldn't be any more baffled.  I left the XIB file in the project with its IBActions and hookups in the XIB and the .h and .m code.  I had been deleting it earlier.  I built the storyboard with the same IBActions, but didn't included the storyboard IBActions or hookups in the .h and .m code...NOW the code runs fine (maybe).  Are you suppose to keep both the XIB and storyboard in the project, but only  put the IBActions and hookups in the code for one of them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your error messages contain the selector `didClickMakePDF` (with no colon, so no argument) but your code uses the selector `didClickMakePDF:` (with a colon, so expecting one argument).  These are different selectors.

In your storyboard, you need to delete the connections from your buttons to those (incorrect) actions and create connections from the buttons to the correct actions.

#### UPDATE

Sometimes the storyboard editor (“Interface Builder” or IB) gets out of sync with the source code, remembering methods that you've deleted or ignoring methods that you've created.  Here are some things to try, in increasing order of brutality:

1. Make sure all files are saved.  (Command-Option-S saves all files.)
2. Close all files in the project window by pressing Control-Command-W repeatedly, until the editor window is blank.
3. Quit and restart Xcode.
4. Clean your build folder by pressing Option-Shift-Command-K.
5. Delete your Derived Data folder for the project.  Close your project, then open the Organizer window and click on the Projects tab.  Click on your project in the left-side list.  Then click the Delete… button to the right of the Derived Data line in the right-side pane.

#### UPDATE 2

When you delete a resource file (like a xib file) from your app and then run the app, Xcode doesn't delete the resource file from the app installation on the simulator or device.  You need to delete the app entirely from the simulator or device (in the usual way, by making the icons wiggle and then tapping the X button) to remove the obsolete xib file.

Comment: I really appreciate your patience.  When I make the selectors and code are consistent (with colons) I get the same error.  There is something wrong here. I can delete the MTViewController.h and .m and the storyboard so there is no code with didClickMakePDF or didClickMakePDF: selector.  When I add a virtually empty MTViewController.h and .m and a storyboard and designate the ViewController as MTViewController, the inspector panel shows a didClickMakePDF, a didClickMakePDF:, a didClickOpenPDF, and a didClickOpenPDF:.  How is that possible?

Comment: I thought this was solved, but it isn't.  There is no reference to didClickMakePDF in the code, just didClickMakePDF:.  At the button level, all connects are to didClickMakePDF:.  But, at the ViewController level, the connections are there to didClickMakePDF: but there are also unconnected references to didClickMakePDF and the run fails with the same error message re didClickMakePDF being unrecognized.  I have tried your 5 steps several times, and nothing changes.  I can't seem to get rid of the didClickMakePDF references.  Any other suggestions?

Comment: Post a screen shot of your “unconnected references”.

Comment: Could you please tell me how to post a screen shot.  BTW, I noticed that the code is presenting the old xib view even though the xib file was deleted from the project, not the storyboard view. I have a screenshot that shows this also.  This only seems to run if the didClickMakePDF in the .h file is didClickMakePDF: and the code in the .m file is didClickMakePDF.  If I try to make these match, the code crashes.

Comment: Not know anything else, I put the screenshots on a google website. https://sites.google.com/site/jfellowsxcode/

Comment: Thanks. I deleted the app on the simulator, but when I ran it again it still shows the xib view and not the storyboard view.  Trying to convert this xib to storyboard has been enormously time consuming.  Is there a way to run xib and storyboards together in some fashion.  My app is critically dependent on this converted xib code, and I'm making virtually no progress toward finishing this project.

Comment: Out of desperation, I replaced the previous MTViewController with a NewViewController (old content cut and pasted into this).  The nonconnections disappeared, but I got the error message when I tried to run it: 2013-06-06 22:06:53.873 PDFMaker[7082:19d03] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Could not load NIB in bundle: 'NSBundle </Users/kayfellows/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/6.1/Applications/9A22A45B-EAF0-4D04-A69F-257FFDAFA9EE/PDFMaker.app> (loaded)' with name 'NewViewController'' Any suggestions?